# debug mode shows incorrect macro result?

Tags: excel, vba

I created two Worksheets hidden(1) and visible(2) and placed name of the worksheet in A1
i hid the "hidden" Sheet and wrote simple macro

```
ThisWorkbook.activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
Debug.print Cells(1,1).Value
'debug mode: output is "visible" (incorrect)
'normal mode: output is "hidden" (correct)
```

Why the debug mode is showing incorrect result?

Comment: Yes. I was misinterpreting the case. I've removed it.

Comment: @taller in DEBUG mode it takes values from visible sheet.
In normal run, i takes values from the hidden sheet. Why?

Comment: The correct value is actually the visible sheet, because you cannot activate a hidden sheet. When you do so with VBA, the visible sheet will just become active again. It does seem odd that there is a difference between run and debug mode as to whether the visible sheet becomes active again before or after the `.Print`. But perhaps the best way to avoid the problem is to avoid using `.Activate` on a hidden sheet, and to use fully qualified references like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value`

Comment: @Kevin thank You for Your explanation. It is odd , not only in this case, that the debug mode shows different results. Nevertheless i have to get used to it and avoid using "ActiveSheet" as You mentioned.